# IDEA file status icons?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to make IntelliJ IDEA use something other than [color](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-status-highlights.html) to indicate file status?  I find the UX obnoxious and I'm not even colorblind.  I see that there are "bold", "italic", and "effects" options for each of the statuses, but they're all disabled even though I'm using a custom scheme.

Related: Is there a way to make packages and directories indicate the aggregate status of their children?  (I.e., if any file in `com.foo.package` is changed, `com.foo.package` is displayed as changed, as is its parent, all the way to the root.)

Comment: No, no, and no. Sorry. I've never heard anyone call IntelliJ's UX obnoxious before -- given the information density they're dealing with I'd say that they've done quite a good job (maybe not as good as it could be, but pretty good). You can always play with the code -- it is open source after all.

Comment: Regarding the related question, perhaps `File` -> `Settings` -> `Version control` & check `Show directories with changed descendants`, is what you're looking for

Comment: @Morfic Nice!  Thanks.